# Run specific flavor in gradle

Tags: android, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

I wish to run specific flavor in my android gradle file. I have two flavors:

```
productFlavors {

    prod {

    }

    lab {

    }
}
```

The task assebleRelease will run both of them and create two apk files. I need to create task that will run only prod flavor and create 1 apk file. Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select variant as mentioned on screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those tasks should be already created by android gradle plugin.
You can use:

```
gradle assembleProdRelease
gradle assembleLabRelease
```

Or you can use Gradle panel in Android Studio which contains all gradle tasks.

[image: Gradle panel in android studio]

Flavors on example image are named "normal" and "videodebug"